# Do dissolving myelinated connections explain learning?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, learning, theoretical-neuroscience

In order to understand how we get rid of established habits/behavior:
Can myelinated connections be dissolved or are new connections created that bypass those connections?

Comment: My initial question was: "Can myelinated connections be dissolved" which was changed by Seanny123.

Comment: Was my edit unhelpful?

Answer (score 4):

[Myelin](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/002261.htm) is a greatly extended and modified plasma membrane wrapped around the nerve **[axon](http://et%20al.,%20editors.%20Neuroscience.%202nd%20edition.%20Sunderland%20(MA):%20Sinauer%20Associates;%202001.%20Long-Term%20Synaptic%20Depression)** in a spiral fashion [(Morell & Quarles, 1999)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK27954/). It typically forms on long axons to increase conduction speed and efficiency.

Learning predominantly takes place in cortical areas and it is believed that it mainly depends on synaptic changes, such as [long-term potentiation](http://thebrain.mcgill.ca/flash/i/i_07/i_07_m/i_07_m_tra/i_07_m_tra.html) (LTP) of **[synapses](http://www.human-memory.net/brain_neurons.html)**. Forgetting things is believed to be mediated through [long-term depression](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10899/) (LTD).

Both LTP and LTD are synaptic processes and do not involve myelin, as that substance is found around axons. Although there is a lot more to learning than I can cover here, I dare say it doesn't involve myelination, and forgetting things doesn't involve demyelination, or *vice versa*.

[Demyelination](http://www.mayoclinic.org/demyelinating-disease/expert-answers/faq-20058521/) typically results in disease. The most common one being [multiple sclerosis](http://www.webmd.com/multiple-sclerosis/guide/multiple-sclerosis-symptoms), characterized by blurred or double vision,
thinking problems, lack of coordination, loss of balance, numbness, tingling
and weakness in an arm or leg.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Morell & Quarles. The Myelin Sheath. In: Siegel GJ *et al*., (eds). Basic Neurochemistry. 6<sup>th</sup> ed. Philadelphia: Lippincott-Raven (1999)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK27954/)

**-** [Purves *et al*., (eds). Neuroscience. 2<sup>nd</sup> edition. Sunderland (MA): Sinauer Associates; 2001](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10899/)</sub>